# Type cast warning from DWORD to 64 bit pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

An old 32 bit C++ application (MS Visual Studio) has code lines like this:

```
m_value = (PUCHAR)someDWORD;
```

Where PUCHAR is a pointer to an unsigned char.

Now I have changed to 64 bit and I get a (valid) warning about conversion from DWORD to the 64 bit pointer. My unqualified solution to this is to write like this:

```
m_value = (PUCHAR)(DWARD_PTR)someDWORD;
```

Is this the correct way to fix this warning (and potential runtime error)?

Comment: No. The correct way is to fix the place that produces `someDWORD` and make it produce a pointer sized something.

Comment: Maybe, big maybe.  Be sure to run the program on Win8.1 or higher, it flushes out bugs like this by intentionally allocating memory above the 4GB zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That savage cast to `DWORD_PTR` will only pad `someDWORD` with zeros, it won't bring back the upper half of the pointer value that was lost.

You need `someDWORD` to be a `DWORD_PTR` (or, in fact, a `std::uintptr_t`) from the beginning.

Comment: I see, in fact "someDWORD" is a DWORD in a struct that is used everywhere, and I'd like to avoid too much refactoring (just need to make this run in a 64 bit context). Could a solution be to use one of the cast helpers (e.g. using static_cast with uintptr_t, etc)? Or is that the same?

Comment: @Werner If the `DWORD` in the struct is only 32 bits large, then it is impossible in every sense of the word to retrieve the original 64 bits from just that information. You can cast around until the moon turns blue, but unless you store all 64 bits of the pointer value that you need, you won't get the correct value back.

Comment: Put another way: If your country used to have 4 digit ZIP codes but switches to 6 digits, you can't keep giving people forms that only have space for 4 digits. You need to update the forms (your struct), otherwise you won't have any way to retrieve the correct information. Yes, this may even mean changing the size of the paper that the form is printed on (i.e. the size of the struct), which may necessitate more changes.

Comment: @MaxLanghof true, but if the switch to 6 digits was because of some bureaucratic decision to follow EU standards where zip codes are 6 digits...while in reality, there would never, ever be a 6 digit zipcode in my country? We could continue using our forms but when passing on zip codes to the EU, we would just pad them like "001234".

Comment: @Werner That's not the case here though. That place that produces `someDWORD`, it has to start with an actual pointer (returned by the `&` operator or some flavor of `malloc`), and then it casts it to `DWORD`. That is the point of the actual error, everything else is wrong after that, including casting it back to a pointer. You should be getting another warning about writing *to* `someDWORD`, pay attention to that one first.